# Are arbitrary intersection of open sets contained in discrete and trivial topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Recall topology $\tau$ on set $X$:

1. $\varnothing \in \tau$, $X \in \tau$
2. $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha \in \tau$
3. $\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n U_i \in \tau$

I am trying to show that both discrete and trivial topologies are topologies...item 1 and 2 seems to be obvious, and 3 also seems to be obvious but with a twist...

> It seems to me that not only finite intersection are closed in the discrete and the trivial topology, but arbitrary intersection of either case is also closed in the two topologies

Note: "Closed" means "lies in"

> Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Do you mean arbitrary intersections of _open_ sets are _open_? In any topology, it's always the case that arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed.

Comment: @JackLee Ah okay, sorry I meant that "closed" in the topology

Comment: It's not a good idea to use "closed" in this way when talking about topologies. The word has a very specific meaning in the topological context, and this isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, and not hard to prove!  Since the trivial (or indiscrete) topology is finite, all intersections in that topology are equivalent to finite intersections.  And since the discrete topology contains all subsets, in particular it includes any infinite intersection of subsets, because that is also a subset.

Comment: So such arbitrary intersection are also considered open, even though the definition does only includes finite intersection? In other words, let $\tau_{dis}$ be the discrete topology of a set $X$, then $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha$ is open?

Comment: They're not "considered" open.  It's just that in the case of these two topologies, it happens that any arbitrary intersection is also in the topology, and therefore (by definition) is open in that topology.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question to be about the intersection of open sets, not the intersection of closed sets.

Comment: It is my fault. By closed I meant, that arbitrary intersection of open sets lies in the topology

Comment: OK, then my answer does apply.  You could say that both topologies are closed under the operation of taking arbitrary intersections.  But it's confusing to say that any particular intersection is closed, because of the meaning of "closed set" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Note that everyone is closed in the discrete topology, then every intersection of subsets (finite or infinity) is closed. And all possible intersection of open/close subset on the trivial topology is the empty set and X.